# CacheServerApplication unable to connect to Gemfire cluster running apart from localhost

Tags: gemfire, geode, spring-data-gemfire

Can you please provide minimum configuration needed to connect a Gemfire CacheServerApplication as a REPLICATE_PROXY to a Gemfire/Geode cluster running apart from localhost ?

I have a cluster running which I am able to connect from ClientCacheApplication but the same configuration is not working for CacheServerApplication.

Regards,
Malaya

1. Client is able to connect to Cluster.
2. Server with simillar configuration is not able to connect.

Answer (score 1):

Answered by John Blum via Git issues: [634](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/issues/634)

> The later (i.e. GemFire/Geode locators property) is used by nodes (e.g. servers) that a user wants connected to a cluster as a peer member (i.e. Cache instance or Locator instance, in other words, not a client).